# How to sort list of object by ISO8601

Tags: flutter, sorting, listview, iso8601, for-in-loop

I've got a list of object which after looping I'm trying to sort the final list by given **ISO8601** format **favouriteDateTime: 2022-12-16T10:46:55.551Z**. There are mutiple sorting method but which one to use and how to sort it.

```
List<Movies> get Movies{
List<Movies> favMoviesList = <Movies>[];
for (final category in _appData.categories) {
  for (final series in category.series!) {
    final favMovies = series.movie!
        .where((movie) =>
            movie.stats != null && movie.stats!.isFavourite == true)
        .toList();

    if (favMovies.length > 0) {
     
    List<Movies> sorted = favMovies
       ..sort((a, b) => b.stats!.favoriteDateTime!
            .compareTo(a.stats!.favoriteDateTime!));
      favMoviesList.addAll(sorted);
    }}}

return favMoviesList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've already got a working implementation here. ISO8601 timestamps can just be sorted with string comparison - for two ISO strings `a` and `b`, `a > b` will always be true if time `a` is after time `b`, and the inverse is also true.

As far as the actual sorting method goes, you've got the right idea here with using `sort()`. Just make sure you only have one period -- `favMovies.sort()`, not `favMovies..sort()`.

Also, `List.sort()` does not return the sorted list, it sorts the list in place. So your sorting code should be:

```
favMovies.sort((a, b) => 
  b.stats!.favoriteDateTime!.compareTo(a.stats!.favoriteDateTime!)
);
favMoviesList.addAll(favMovies);
```

Comment: For some reason it won't allow sorting orginal array coming from server, however I cloned the original into new one, sorted and returned it. WORKED.